# Collectionview preventing selectionchange

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, collectionview

I am having problem that is probably related the collectionview. The problem seem to be that each group will keep track of its own selector, which will prevent the program from firing a new SelectionChanged event when I select a previously selected item in a previous group.

Example:
Group 1:
row1
row2(selected)
Group 2:
row1 (selected)

If I then first open group 1 and click on row 2, then swap to Group 2 and select the first row. If I then again go back to group 1 and clicks row 2 there won't be a trigger event and the selecteditem will stay the same from group 2, until I click row 1.
Which is a problem because there can be cases where there are only 1 row in a group.

My XAML looks like this (removed unrelated stuff).

```
<DataGrid 
  Margin="0,10,0,0"
  SelectionMode="Single"
  IsReadOnly="True"
  Name="InvoiceGrid"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDiscrepancy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="{Binding RowDetailsVisible}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding InvoiceDiscrepancies}">
  <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                  <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FF002255" >
                    <Expander.Header>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Textblocks for design here.../>
                      </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.Content>
                      <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander.Content>
                  </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <Columns here/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <style for animating the expanding/>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <ListBox Name="listBox3" 
            SelectionMode="Single"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource invoiceItemTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Invoices, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedInvoice, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

So, anyone know what might be the solution? Is it possible to have one selector between the groups, or should I somehow clear the selector when I select a new row in the parent datagrid?

EDIT:
Github repo with an example of the issue
https://github.com/Snuffsis/GroupingSelect

Comment: Could you provide more details or an published example? On a high-level it seems there is a problem with the SelectedItem binding (invoice). Tried to play with it and it seems works as expected w/o  RelativeSource in the binding. https://github.com/zanybaka/StackOverflow.com/tree/master/Questions/64701419/WpfApp1

Comment: @ZanyBaka I have added a Github repo with an example of the issue here https://github.com/Snuffsis/GroupingSelect
If i remove the relativesource part. Then I don't get a SelectionChanged event at all either, so that didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no needs to keep all the selected listbox items you can just clear the selection.

As an option you can raise PropertyChanged with the null value to clear the current selection.

```
public Invoice SelectedInvoice
{
    get => _selectedInvoice;
    set
    {
        if (_selectedInvoice != value)
        {
            if (_selectedInvoice != null) // <- add the 'if' block
            {
                _selectedInvoice = null;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedInvoice);
            }
            _selectedInvoice = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedInvoice);
        }
    }
}
```